# A random variable has cumulative distribution function F(x) = 0 if x < -2...

Tags: probability

A random variable has cumulative distribution function $$F(x) =\begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if}& x < -2\\.2 &\mbox{if}& -2 ≤ x < 0\\.5 &\mbox{if}& 0 ≤ x < 1.1\\1 &\mbox{if}& x ≥ 1.1\end{cases}$$

a) Find P{X=-1 or X=0}

b) Find P{-1 ≤ X ≤ .5}

So far I graphed it since F(x) is a step function. But I am not sure how to compute the values after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilise the following:

$\begin{align}F(x^+)&=\lim\limits_{h\,\downarrow\,x} F(h)\\[1ex]F(x^-)&=\lim\limits_{k\,\uparrow\,x}F(k)\\[1ex]\mathsf P(X{\leq}x)&=F(x^+)\\[1ex]\mathsf P(X{\lt}x)&=F(x^-)\\[1ex]\mathsf P(X{=}x)&=F(x^+)-F(x^-)\\[1ex]\mathsf P(a\leq X\leq b)&= F(b^+)-F(a^-)\end{align}$

So, for example: $\mathsf P(X{=}0)$ $=0.5-0.2\\=0.3$

Comment: So  {-1 ≤ X ≤ .5} = 0.3?

Comment: $\mathsf P(-1\leq X\leq .5)=0.3$, yes.

Comment: Sorry another question but how would I compute P{X=-1 or X=0} when P(X=-1) = 0 and P(X=0) 0.3? I know that I have to use P(X = -1 or X = 0) = P(X = -1) + P(X = 0) - P(X = 1 and X = 0) but how would I get P(X = 1 and X = 0)?

Comment: Since $X$ may realise only one value, **zero** is the probability for it having two distinct values.